# How do I always run in low graphics mode?

Tags: login, 10.04

How do I always run in low graphics mode?  In normal mode my computer crashes unexpectedly every now and again which is very frustrating when work is lost.  After a crash, it gives me the option to log in using the low graphics mode.  In this mode, my computer never seems to crash.

So does anyone know how I can always start in low graphics mode?

I get this problem in Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Do you mean the safemode from the login screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following. Go to System-administration-login screen and change to the safemode[image]